# Ember js get object from previous route

Tags: ember.js

I am building my first EmberJS app.

Initially from index route, I will display an A. When user click A, it will route to `/a`. Component A will have a field `url`, after fill in and click a button, it will route to `/b`. Component B also has a field email. Fill in and click a button it will route to `/summary` which displays what I filled in A and B. How could I do it in best practice?

I am using `ember-cli` and `this.transitionTo(/b)` to go to route `/b`

Comment: Instead of specifying the url, you can pass route name `this.transitionTo('a')`

Comment: You should build an ember-twiddle for this. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like nested routes would be good for this implementation.
/a - route

```
model(){
 return {url:'default'};
}
```

a.hbs

```
{{comp-a model=model}}
```

/a/b - route

```
model(){
 return {email:''};
}
```

a/b.hbs

```
{{comp-b model=model}}
```

/a/b/summary - route

```
model(){
 return {amodel:this.modelFor('a'),bmodel:this.modelFor('b')};
}
```

a/b/summary.hbs

```
{{comp-a model=model.amodel }}
{{comp-b model=model.bmodel }}
```

Comment: Can't I do a shared store like what ReactJS does and import anywhere? So far i couldn't find how to do so

Comment: Yes .that is an another option, you can do it by creating [services](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/applications/services/#toc-toggle). such a way you can inject it in anywhere to get data

Comment: if i use {{#link-to}}, the service will be gone?

Comment: It wont. Here is definition for `Ember.Service` is an Ember object that lives for the duration of the application, and can be made available in different parts of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that explains exactly how to make a multi-step form like you are asking for.  http://romulomachado.github.io/2016/12/06/multi-step-form-with-ember.html

Using a nested route system, this is fairly straight forward.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('checkout', function() {
    this.route('personal-info');
    this.route('shipping-info');
    this.route('payment-info');
    this.route('confirmation');
  });
});
```

and then you can use an 'order' or some 'form' model to keep the information alive.

I followed the example and built one out with the ability to edit and confirm at the end too. : )